# What type is this connector?

Tags: connector

Can anybody tell me the name of the connector shown in these photos? (I mean the biggest one, which is centered in the photos)

[image: First connector photo]

[image: Second connector photo]

Comment: Interestingly non-typical board that uses component value designators instead of reference designators.

Comment: Since some have asked, the pitch is actually pretty close to 0.156'', as many have guessed.

Comment: -1 and vote to close. This is clearly a shopping question where the OP hasn't even bothered to try to identify the connector.

Comment: @EMFields I tried, I searched on the web, but there are a lot of connectors out there and I could not find it. Do you have good resources to find connectors quickly? How do you know that I did not try? It is not a shopping question: I am not asking "Where do I buy it?", but "What is it?".

Comment: "I want to buy..." targets it as a shopping question, and its manufacturer can be used to connect the dots to a distributor, therefore killing two birds with one stone and solving a logistics, not a design problem. A good starting point to find connectors quickly would be DigiKey's menu system, where starting at the top and punching in:Product Index > Connectors, Interconnects > Rectangular Connectors - Headers, Male Pins will lead you to a page where exactly what you want exists and, since you know the number of pins, the pins' cross-sectional dimensions and pitch, you can easily find it.

Comment: My intention does not impact on the substance of the question, which is "What is this?" and not "Where or how do I buy it?". I could have said "I want to check out specs of this", instead of "I want to buy this", and the question would have been the same. Thanks for the reference, anyway. I had tried other suppliers, but could not find that piece.

Comment: There! I've edited out the hints of a shopping question and turned it into a "identify this component" which are better accepted here.

Comment: FYI: The spacing is nominally 4mm and these are known as 0.156" connectors AS 0.156" is ALMOST exactly 4mm (actually 0.95% lower). Presumably calling them 0.157(4803...) inch connectors was deemed not euphonic enough for whatever reason. [[ By definition 1 inch = 0.0254000000000....  metre)]]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That connector looks to me to be a power type connector with connector pins on 0.156" centers. You can find styles of these from mainstream connector manufacturers such as TE, Molex and others.

[image]

This connector for example is Molex part number 09-65-2068 which you can find at www.mouser.com.

In the industry these are often called KK series connectors.

Answer (score 3):

It is a 0.156"-pitch connector, very common for power connections. One popular line is made by Molex.

Comment: Sorry to be pendantic, but this is 0.156" pitch as you've identified, but it's not Mini-Fit, it's KK, here's the link http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=kk_396&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=power_connectors , the key difference is that Mini fit has pins which are 100% individually shrouded.

Answer (score -3):

Looks like a 0.1" pitch connector. They're very common, but there isn't a generic name for them. Just use any popular distributor's website and filter on the pitch dimension.

Comment: It might be 2.5mm pitch - are your eyes that good?

Comment: Coincidentally, good to +/- 0.04mm ;). It would probably behoove the OP to take out his calipers though.

Comment: No, it's a 0.156"-pitch connector, very common for power connections. Compare the spacing in the first picture to the 0.05" lead spacing of the SOIC nearby. Also, you can see 0.100"-pitch connectors in the second picture, on the right side.